# Differentiating between Elementary and Non Elementary reaction

Tags: kinetics

Is it possible to tell just by looking(reaction's equation) that whether a given is reaction is elementary or non elementary ?

Comment: No, nobody on Earth can say that just by looking at the reaction equation.

Comment: There are ways to experimental assess elemetary vs. non elementary reactions. See here https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-determine-whether-a-reaction-is-elementary-or-not

Comment: Sometimes an educated guess can be made, though.

Comment: You can't even necessarily decide for sure with an experiment.

Comment: I think the wikipedia gives a pretty clear exposition on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_reaction

Answer (score 1):

**Reactions that are probably not elementary**

Whenever there are more than three reactants, it is unlikely that the reaction is elementary. Tenary elementary reactions are already quite rare. If you have a reaction like

$$\ce{2C8H18 + 25 O2 -> 16 CO2 + 18 H2O}$$

it is impossible for 27 particles to come together at once, so you would expect some intermediates. Even for a reaction with just 3 reactant molecules such as

$$\ce{CH4 + 2O2 -> CO2 + 2H2O}$$

it is highly unlikely that a single collision would be sufficient to break 6 bonds and make 6 new ones.

Conversely, a reaction with a single product such as

$$\ce{O + O2 -> O3}$$

is probably not bimolecular because there is no way of getting rid of the excess energy. Instead, the reaction proceeds like this:

$$\ce{O + O2 + X -> O3 + X}$$

where X is "a third molecule" that leaves the collision chemically unchanged but with higher kinetic energy (source: https://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/wxwise/ozone/OZONE2.html).

**Reactions where you can't tell**

Bimolecular simple reactions could well be elementary, but often are not. The reaction

$$\ce{H2 + I2 -> 2 HI}$$

shows two distinct mechanisms, one with one elementary step as written (the iodine has to be vibrationally excited, favored by high temperature) and the other one with iodine first dissociating into iodine atoms (source: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-80299-7_12).

**Is it possible to tell just by looking whether a given is reaction is elementary or non elementary?**

No, but sometimes it is obvious that the reaction has to be multi-step. In cases where a mechanism is dependent not only on the net reaction, but also on reaction conditions, it becomes obvious that just knowing the net reaction is not sufficient.

Comment: I am not sure about $\ce{N2O4}$.According to the definition of an elementary reaction, I would argue that in a steady-state all that matters there is what fraction of molecules are activated, not how they become activated. The temperature would define the Boltzmann fraction of activated molecules.

Comment: @BuckThorn Good point. For atmospheric reactions (ozone...) the mechanism sometimes includes a second unspecified molecule that does not react, but is involved in a collision.

Comment: So the idea is that a collision with an inert gas will transfer more energy than would a collision with another molecule of the same type? Is that what makes the reaction not "unimolecular"? But don't all gas molecules - assuming ideality - carry on average $3kT/2$ of kinetic energy? Another way of putting it is that the reaction is unimolecular in the activated species, and the fraction of activated species depends on T, not on the gas composition. So my point remains, what makes the dissociation of $\ce{N2O4}$ not elementary?

Comment: Cannot consider myself an expert on the subject, but this suggests the dissociation is unimolecular: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257992714_Transition_state_and_dynamics_of_unimolecular_no-barrier_fragmentation_Thermal_dissociation_of_N2O4

Comment: @BuckThorn Yes, you are right. I will fix it.